# Completed master level study in bachelor second year can i do direct Phd

Tags: phd

---

Can one do Phd in mathematics directly after completing bachelors in mathematics

Comment: This is the usual process in the United States, but customs are different in some other places.

Comment: "Can one do" whatever is a really ambiguous question. Yes, a genius might get PhD right after his/her elementary school (at least hypothetically) but normal people usually complete bachelor, and depending on the country, they might enter a master degree to become familiar with research and then after that start their PhD possibly or as @AndreasBlass said sometimes in the US, undergraduates go directly to PhD after completing their bachelor. In fact in the US, it is graduate school and you can start it with the intention of getting master but at some point you might want to switch to PhD.

Comment: Sir i am from India and there one has to do masters also for a Phd

Comment: The university will have its own rules for such things. The rules might include the possibility of exceptions, or not. You need to ask them. But, I think the probability is low.

Comment: In Germany, programs that allow you to skip the Master's would be known as "fast-track PhD program". A few universities/departments have such a program, but not all.

Answer (score 1):

**This will depend on the university and on your capacities**.  Here is an example from my institution, which dose allow for direct-entry into a mathematics PhD:

> Exceptional applicants may be considered for direct entry to the PhD program from a Bachelor’s program. Applicants should have a strong academic record. Applicants are strongly encouraged to discuss their interest in direct entry with prospective supervisors. Applications that are not admitted for direct entry to PhD will still be considered for admission to the Master's program.

So yes, it is possible, but my expectation is that it is extremely rare.  It will also depend on the institution.  As you said, in your country it does not appear to be a possiblity.